# Making date comparison work with different language settings at DB and Application

Tags: .net, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a Linq to Entity query that compares dates. I'm querying a SQL server 2008 database whose language is US English. My application handles dates in dd/MM/yyyy format.

```
itemList = from i in _context.Items
    select i;

DateTime utcStartDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(StartDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime utcEndDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(EndDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var items= from i in itemList
       where c.ModifiedDate.Date >= utcStartDate.Date  &&
             c.ModifiedDate.Date <= utcEndDate.Date
       select i;
```

Here `StartDate` and `EndDate` are `DateTime` objects, which are read from textboxes (only dates are entered) and converted to DateTime. Typical values are: `{8/3/2012 12:00:00 AM}` for 08 March 2012.

This is how the value is specified when the column is updated in the database:

```
    item.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
```

**I cannot change the language settings at the Server.** Is there any way to read the data from the SQL server and convert it to the "dd/MM/yyyy" format before comparing the dates?
Alternatively, what fornat should I convert the Datetime variables to so that the comparison works? What is the correct and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format only applies when treating the data as strings. The code shown doesn't do that! It compares them as dates, transferring the parameters in their binary representation. Thus, there **is** no ambiguity, and no formatting involved at any point.

Basically, this isn't a problem. What you are asking is actually pretty similar to saying "how does SQL server order integers as "1,2,...,9,10,11" and not "1,10,11,2,...9" - to which the answer is "because it isn't treating them as strings".

To be specific, datetime in sql server is actually treated as a decimal number, with the integer part being the day and the decimal part being the time; any "dd/MM/yyyy" or "yyyy/MM/dd" etc exists **only** for us poor fleshy readers. The server is not confused by such things.

Comment: That's strange. I'm at a loss here...It isn't working for me when the DateTime objects in the where clause are in dd/MM/YYYY. No results are returned. I changed the jquery datepicker format to yy-mm-dd. That seems to work.

Comment: @escist there is **no such thing** as a "DateTime ... in dd/MM/YYYY" - that is an oxymoron; a datetime **is a number** - not a string, and it has **no concept** of format, in exactly the way that an integer is neither "12345" nor "12,345.0" - it is just an integer 123, with no notion of string representation.

Comment: @escist I **suspect** the real issue here is simply that your values of `StartDate` and `EndDate` are... just wrong!

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but it simply does not seem to work. The ranges are fine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @escist you need to check what the values are that are in StartDate and EndDate; I *suspect* the issue is in parsing the inputs to populate those 2 values; but that has nothing to do with LINQ or the database server

Comment: I added breakpints and copied the values of the `DateTime` objects. Does not work for:
StartDate = {8/3/2012 12:00:00 AM}
EndDate = {12/3/2012 12:00:00 AM}
Works for:
{3/8/2012 12:00:00 AM}
{3/12/2012 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: @escist it is hard to tell from that (ambiguous); it would be adviseable to look at the values to see what the month is

Comment: You're right. The Datetime objects for dd/MM/yyyy scenarios have incorrect values for month and day (they get swapped).

Answer (score 1):

if you use `DateTime` objects in your linq query on c# side of things and `date` objects in your sql server column definitions, it should be correctly handled by linq2sql. In short you don't have to do anyting.

So.

What is the problem you're trying to solve?

This line makes me think that you have problems with timezones, not regional date time formats:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(EndDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

And yes, as in other response, DateTime data type will be handled automatically in linq2entities. So you only need to worry about regional date formats when presenting data to the user via .ToString() or other methods.

Comment: I'm using UTC just to remove any ambiguity between timezones.